# Microsoft Graph: Can't create a planner task with expiration date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, httprequest

I created a Microsoft Graph request with the following JSON body:

```
{
   "planId":"uiceFoBwgUmRrejVaf0z1ZcADEOr",
   "title":"test task",
   "assignments":{
      "caf39f72-6600-41f7-a30a-2574cfa831af":{
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
         "orderHint":" !"
      }
   },
   "dueDateTime":{
      "dateTime":"2021-08-29T04:00:00:00Z",
      "timeZone":"GMT+1"
   }
}
```

I sent the body via HTTP POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks while being authorized. This was the message it gave me:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid:\r\nAn unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'dueDateTime' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-09T10:51:41",
            "request-id": "f5acd6d0-f23a-48ac-ad14-5cb086695104",
            "client-request-id": "11d32e3c-2093-0aba-5740-45174cec76ac"
        }
    }
}
```

What does this error mean? Did I type the `dueDateTime` argument wrong? Or does it need another argument in order to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the same request with beta as you specified the dueDateTime in [DateTimeTimeZone format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlooktask-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planner due date is DateTimeOffset, the structure you are trying to pass in is a DateTimeTimeZone.

Your input should look like this:

```
"dueDateTime":"2021-08-29T04:00:00+01:00",
```

You can read more about the properties and their types from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0).